# Last step in moving to XeTeX: Font shape problems

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am trying to move to the XeTeX distribution. My current problem is the following:

If I leave these packages I have no problems with the Helvetica.

```
\usepackage[portuges,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

However, if I define the XeTeX packages and font like:

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Helvetica}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\setotherlanguage{portuges}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

Then I get warnings about missing font shapes, namely:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/phv/b/n' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/Helvetica(0)/m/sc' undefined
```

I have also tried:

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

But then the font shapes got even worse.

Has someone faced this problem?

EDIT:

Now I have the following packages:

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[
        Extension=.otf,
        UprightFont= *-regular,
        BoldFont=*-bold,
        ItalicFont=*-italic,
        BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
    ]{texgyreheros}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\setotherlanguage{portuges}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

And the template I started with has the following command:

```
\newcommand{\helv}{ % 
\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
```

I honestly don't know what it is doing to the font, but I do know it's the last resistant`:)`.

Warning is:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/phv/b/n' undefined
```

If I remove the `\fontfamily` command I get

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/texgyreheros(0)/b/n' undefined
```

This command is being applied in the Header and Footer of the document.

I don't know what the `\fontfamily` does, but I assume `\fontseries` defines the font to be Bold. Is there a redefinition of the command required to match XeTeX?

Comment: is your Helvetica family complete, e.g. do you have bold, italics, small caps, and bold italics versions of the helvetica font? /m/sc is the small caps variant. If you don't have small caps of Helvetica, then you won't be able to load /m/sc.

Comment: I don't have them, can they be found in the internet? (I am talking legit scenarios)

Comment: As far as I know there is no small caps variant of Helvetica. The `helvet` package uses faked small caps and [Linotype doesn't sell any small caps variant](http://www.linotype.com/526/helvetica-family.html).

Comment: I assume there is no _workaround_ then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [TeX Gyre fonts](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/) typically come with small caps. TeX Gyre Heros looks very similar to Helvetica (technically, it is based on URW Nimbus Sans L; so it has the same font metrics as Helvetica, but the characters might look slightly different­­­­). The fonts are probably already installed with your TeX distribution. To use them form there in XeLaTeX, you have to call them the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont= *-regular,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
]{texgyreheros}

\begin{document}
    CGRart \textsc{CGRart}
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyra Heros sample]

Comment: I am going to try this later today.

Comment: This works wonders. However I have one last detail to iron out all warnings. I have added it to my question above.

Comment: @tiago instead of writing \fontshape{b} just write \bfseries.

Answer (score 6):

As Caramdir mentions in his comment, Helvetica doesn't come with small caps, and it doesn't seem that many free fonts (and even many professional fonts) come with real small caps.  Will Robertson recommended the following workaround on the XeTeX mailing list a couple of years ago.

> In the past I've thought about this in fontspec, but it really becomes impossible if you want the fake small caps to behaviour like \textsc -- that is, to have uppercase come out as real uppercase but lowercase   to come out as scaled uppercase.
>
> So rather than using fontspec, it's probably easier to use the relsize package, like this:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{fontspec,relsize}
> \begin{document}
> \fontspec{Georgia}
> THIS IS UPPERCASE and lowercase
> {\smaller THIS IS FAKE SMALL CAPS}
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> You can always define a macro to make this more "semantic", as well:
>
> `\newcommand\fakesc[1]{{\smaller #1}}`

Original message [here](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2008-July/010326.html).

Comment: Even though I've upvoted you for quoting me — `:)` — for this very specific question regarding Helvetica I think Caramdir's answer hits the nail on the head. For arbitrary fonts, however, your answer here is the best you can do.

Comment: @Will: I think your vote didn't register.

Comment: @Will I gave up looking through all the fonts on my system and stopped at 'S'.  If I'd been more persistent I would have come up with Caramdir's solution.  I was trying to find a substitute font and failed through exhaustion.

Comment: If one is looking for replacements/extensions of popular fonts, TeX Gyre is a good place to start. I would have posted that solution earlier today, but I was under the impression that Heros doesn't have small caps.

Comment: @Caramdir vote fixed, not sure about how that happened.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to post my results with this - it seems the biggest problem is font encoding; apparently neither `\sffamily` nor `\sfdefault` handle it - so while one can set "`phv`" as the `helvet`ica font in diverse ways, that font seemingly only exists in T1 encoding. One sign of this is if I compile the below example with `pdflatex` (*previously removing all `fontspec`-related stuff*) - and I get upon loading of `helvet.sty`:

```
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd
File: ot1phv.fd 2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
```

The problem is then, that `fontspec` will switch to a different encoding - EU1 if you build with `xelatex`, and EU2 if with `lualatex` (or at least that is how I've seen it so far). And so, `\sffamily` may tell fontspec to look for `phv`, but if the encoding is set to EU2, then `fontspec` looks for `EU2/phv` which doesn't exist (instead of `T1/phv` which does).

The solution seems to be to issue a command like this explicitly:

```
\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
```

... and as the below MWE shows, I haven't found a way how to redefine `\sffamily` or `\sfdefault` to also switch to T1 encoding (like with explicit `\fontencoding{T1}`). Another way could - conceivably - be, to use something like:

```
\DeclareFontShape{EU2}{phv}{m}{n}{<->ssub * phv/bx/n}{} % nope
```

... in the spirit of font "mapping" as in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56097/2595) (*where `xelatex` is used to generate a fake-bold smallcaps family; and the missing bold smallcaps from the original font is mapped to the fake-bold one*); unfortunately, it seems `\DeclareFontShape` can only map between fonts of the same encoding - I cannot see a way to specify something line T1 on the right-hand side.

The output of the MWE is this (*click for full res*):

[image: test.png]

... and this is what `pdffonts` sees there:

```
$ pdffonts test.pdf 
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
UGSGGF+Junicode                      CID TrueType      yes yes yes      8  0
GEDPKS+LMRoman10-Regular             CID Type 0C       yes yes yes      9  0
ZRGIMP+NimbusSanL-Bold               Type 1            yes yes no      10  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no      11  0
EURSKX+Junicode-Bold                 CID TrueType      yes yes yes     12  0
```

... and this is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Junicode}

\usepackage[left=10pt,right=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{helvet}

% for debugging fonts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14382/2595
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showfont}{Encoding: \f@encoding{},
  Family: \f@family{},
  Series: \f@series{},
  Shape: \f@shape{},
  Size: \f@size{},
  \edef\tmpfn{\font@name}
  font@name: \meaning\font@name \\
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  Testing 1 \showfont

    \sffamily\selectfont

  Testing 2 \showfont

    % texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty
    \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}\sfdefault\selectfont

  Testing 3 \showfont

    \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\bfseries\selectfont

  Testing 4 \showfont % macro:->\T1/phv/bx/n/12

    \rmfamily\selectfont

  Testing 5 \showfont

    \fontencoding{EU2}\selectfont

  Testing 6 \showfont

    \sffamily\selectfont

  Testing 7 \showfont

    \fontencoding{T1}\selectfont

  Testing 8 \showfont

    \fontencoding{EU2}\rmfamily\selectfont

  Testing 9 \showfont

%     \DeclareFontShape{EU2}{phv}{m}{n}{<->ssub * phv/bx/n}{} % nope
%     \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\T1/phv/bx/n/12} % nope
    \sffamily\selectfont

  Testing 10 \showfont

    \typeout{ .. \expandafter\meaning\csname sffamily \endcsname -- \meaning\sffamily} %  .. \long macro:->\not@math@alphabet \sffamily \mathsf \fontfamily \sfdefault \selectfont -- macro:->\protect \sffamily
    \typeout{ .. \expandafter\meaning\csname sfdefault \endcsname -- \meaning\sfdefault} % \relax-- \long macro:->phv
    \typeout{ .. \expandafter\meaning\csname fontfamily \endcsname -- \meaning\fontfamily} % \long macro:#1->\edef \f@family {#1}-- macro:->\protect \fontfamily
    \typeout{ .. \expandafter\meaning\csname selectfont \endcsname -- \meaning\selectfont} %

\end{document}
```

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!