# Small caps with TeX Gyre Heros (via unicode-math/fontspec) in beamer

Tags: beamer, fontspec, unicode-math

I would like to use small caps for short text sections in a `beamer` presentation. In a normal `article`, the following produces small caps in the TeX Gyre Heros font, as shown [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10204/32374):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Test text} Test text
\end{document}
```

while the following `beamer` document produces a warning and serif small caps:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\textsc{Test text} Test text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/lmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `EU2/lmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 9.
```

How can I use small caps with [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math)/[`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) in `beamer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`beamer` uses the Sans Serif font as default.

So setting

```
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
```

instead of

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
```

works for me.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\textsc{Test text} \textsf{Test text}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! +1 Can you explain how `setmainfont` interacts with beamer to produce sans-serif font for everything except small caps?

Comment: @darthbith I'm afraid not...

Comment: OK guess I have to do some research! Thanks again :-)

Comment: @darthbith You're welcome.