# Font for small caps in (French style) figure caption labels

Tags: xetex, captions, memoir, fontspec

Polyglossia `{french}` in Memoir Class.  My preferred font is Open Sans. MWE compiled with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{french}
  \setmainfont{Open Sans}
\begin{document}
  C'est un test pour "small caps": Fig.~\ref{fig:myfigure}.
  \begin{figure}[ht] \centering
    \includegraphics{nothing}
    \caption{c'est ma figure}\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

- generates warning:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/OpenSans(0)/m/sc' undefined
>   (Font)              using`EU1/OpenSans(0)/m/n' instead on input line 10.

The output is perfectly readable, but with normal font for "Fig" in the caption:
[image: fallback French caption label in Open Sans]

In an attempt to get rid of the warning, and have French-style "Fig" shape, I tried to have small caps rendered in a font that can handle them (like one of the `TeX Gyre`s), but nothing would work on my Arch Linux Tex-Live setup.

Changing the `setmainfont` line to [use TeX Gyre Heros, like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10214/48816):

```
\setmainfont[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont= *-regular,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
]{texgyreheros}
```

- does work:

[image: correct shaped French caption label in TeX Gyre Heros]

- but for my document, TeX Gyre Heros is a little heavy.

**Is there a way to make the caption use a small-caps-compatible font (ideal), or to not use small-caps at all (thus removing the `Warning`)?**

My various attempts, [like](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/928/48816) `\[captionnamefont]{\upshape}`, achieved nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit here is the file `gloss-french.ldf` which has

```
\def\figurename{\textsc{Fig.}}
```

so you can override this using, for example,

```
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\figurename{Fig.}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setmainfont{Open Sans}

\addto\captionsfrench{\def\figurename{Fig.}}  

\begin{document}
  C'est un test pour "small caps": Fig.~\ref{fig:myfigure}.
  \begin{figure}[ht] \centering
    \includegraphics{nothing}
    \caption{c'est ma figure}\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The only other part in which small-caps are forced is for the table name, so you might need also

```
\def\tablename{Tab.}
```

inside the `\addto\captionsfrench`

Comment: Ah yes, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/blob/master/tex/gloss-french.ldf).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know whether there is a suitable font for your needs, but if you don't want to use small caps at all, you can add these lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\scshape}{\upshape}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{french}
  \setmainfont{Open Sans}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\scshape}{\upshape}
\begin{document}
  C'est un test pour "small caps": Fig.~\ref{fig:myfigure}.
  \begin{figure}[ht] \centering
    \includegraphics{nothing}
    \caption{c'est ma figure}\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since `\textsc` internally uses `\scshape`, it's necessary to redefine only the latter, but it should be better done with `\LetLtxMacro` (see [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/)

Comment: @egreg You're right thanks. Changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: This answer is possibly more generally helpful, but for my needs Gonzalo Medina's answer seems more succinct.